# Metric to identify gradual increases in a slope

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization

```r
date <- seq(as.Date('2020-08-01'), as.Date('2020-08-08'), by="day")
groupA <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
groupB <- c(1,5,1,6,1,1,7,8)
df <- data.frame(date,groupA,groupB)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!date, names_to = "group", values_to = "count")%>%
 ggplot( aes(x=date, y=count, group=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=group))+
  geom_point(aes(color=group))
```

The above code gives the below graph:

[image: scatterplot with two groups]

There are two groups, both values start at 1 and end at 8.
If I calculate the slope for the 8 days, the value would be the same (7/8=0.875).
However, group A is a gradual increase whereas group B is more erratic.
I am after a metric that would identify group A as being a gradual increase because calculating the slope doesn't work for this. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Would an analysis on the fluctuation in _the inter-day difference_ (i.e. x_t - x_{t-1}) achieve what you want? Otherwise one would require the context to provide any useful suggestion.

Comment: Why would calculating the slope not work in group A? Also: Where does the 8 in 7/8 stem from? Both curves show in increase of 7 over a 7 day period. Those things are distracting and make it hard to understand the core of the question. A possible answer may be the $R^2$ but I find it hard to tell.